# Turn on 'App Service Authentication' for Azure Active Directory from terraform script

Tags: azure, terraform

Need to turn on 'App Service Authentication' for Active Directory from my terraform script.

When I add the auth_settings section to my azurerm_app_service resource using the client_id of the app_service I am creating I get the error

'self reference not allowed'

Makes sense but then were to I turn on authentication for the item I am creating?

````
  name                = "${var.prefix}-${var.environment_code}-${var.environment_segment_code}-web"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.my_resource_group.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.my_resource_group.name}"
  app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.my_app_service_plan.id}"

  app_settings = {
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = "${azurerm_application_insights.my_insights.instrumentation_key}"
  }

  tags = {
    my-Environment = "${var.environment}"
    my-Location    = "${var.country}"
    my-Stack       = "${var.stack}"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "app_settings"
    ]
  }

  auth_settings {
    enabled = true
    active_directory {
      client_id = "${azurerm_app_service.web.client_id}"
    }
    default_provider = "AzureActiveDirectory"
  }
}```

I'd like to have ad authentication enabled for my website when I terraform.
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [azurerm_app_service](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html)

A `active_directory` block supports the following:

> client_id - (Required) The Client ID of this relying party
>   application. Enables OpenIDConnection authentication with Azure Active
>   Directory.

There is no direct `client_id` attribute in the `azurerm_app_service` block, you need to register the App Service app in Azure Active Directory then add the `Application (client) ID` on the Azure portal in the `active_directory` block. See the details about [configure your App Service app to use Azure Active Directory sign-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad).

The Azure Active Directory resources have been split out into a new AzureAD Provider - as such the AzureAD resources within the AzureRM Provider are deprecated and will be removed in the next major version (2.0). You could do it with [azuread_application](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/r/application.html) block.

For example, this works for me with 
Terraform v0.12.5
+ provider.azuread v0.5.1
+ provider.azurerm v1.32.0

```
# Configure the Microsoft Azure Active Directory Provider
provider "azuread" {
  version = "~> 0.3"
}

# Create an application
resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  name = "${var.prefix}-app-service"
  homepage                   = "https://${var.prefix}-app-service"
  identifier_uris            = ["https://${var.prefix}-app-service"]
  reply_urls                 = ["https://${var.prefix}-app-service.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback"]
  available_to_other_tenants = false
  oauth2_allow_implicit_flow = true

}
```

and

```
 auth_settings  {
     enabled = true 

     active_directory  {
         client_id = "${azuread_application.example.application_id}"
     }
     default_provider = "AzureActiveDirectory"
     issuer = "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxtenantID/"

}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I am currently using azurerm_app_service to provision my app service.  Are you saying I need to use azuread_application instead?  Or, can azuread_application reference an existing app_service?

Comment: I mean you need provider "azuread" for the azuread partition. I just use azuread partition with a separate .tf file, this can reference a generating azurerm_app_service.

Comment: @NancyXiong Can I use Terrafrom to carry out the app registration in Azure AD?